# Is there a way to change the index's of csv file to a desired format while importing csv to mongodb?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am a beginner to all type of programming. Hence I request your valuable feedbacks regarding the same.
I have 2 different csv files that I want to import to mongodb. But the problem is although the indexes represent the same values the indexes are different.

```
#First CSV file

{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "61bc4217ed94f9d5fe6a350c"
    },
    "Telephone Number": "8429950810",
    "Date of Birth": "01/01/1945"
}

{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "61bc4217ed94f9d5fe6a350c"
    },
    "Telephone Number": "8129437810",
    "Date of Birth": "01/01/1998"
}

#Second CSV file

{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "61bd98d36cc90a9109ab253c"
    },
    "TELEPHONE_NUMBER": "9767022829",
    "DATE_OF_BIRTH": "16-Jun-98"
}

{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "61bd98d36cc9090109ab253c"
    },
    "TELEPHONE_NUMBER": "9567085829",
    "DATE_OF_BIRTH": "16-Jan-91"
}
```

So is there a way to create a common index while importing the csv files to mongo or a way to change index of second csv file to match the first csv file. I am using pymongo for all operations.

Thankyou

Comment: These files are in [JSON](https://json.org) format, not [CSV](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4180). I don´t know much about Mongo, but it might be helpful to provide the table structure you want to import into, what happens when you do so, and what you want instead. See [ask].

Comment: @Robert I should have clarified that in the question. The JSON format is due to mongo db reading csv files as JSON files. When I import the csv files the result in JSON are shown above.